# from_unixtime in miliseconds

Tags: date, pyspark, time

In pyspark, I have a column with a timestamp in milisecond (`bigInt`). I want to convert in Date Format. I use `from_unixtime`.
My current code:

```
Format_Date = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

df = df.withColumn("H_evenement", from_unixtime(df["time"]/lit(1000), Format_Date))
```

This function work in second, so my `SSS` is always `ss.000`. But I would like keep my accurency in milisecond.

How may I do that ?

Thanks!

In pyspark, I want to convert a timestamp from milisecond (`bigInt`) to Date `Format_Date = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"`.

Comment: Please give or show some sample data to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `date_format` function instead of the `from_unixtime` function in PySpark.

See the below implementation for details -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# create sample dataframe with timestamp column in milliseconds
data = [("foo", 1647932442000), ("bar", 1647932443000), ("baz", 1647932444000)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "time"])

Format_Date = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

# convert timestamp in milliseconds to date format with millisecond precision
df = df.withColumn("H_evenement", date_format((col("time")/1000).cast("timestamp"), Format_Date))

# show resulting dataframe
df.show(truncate=False)

+----+-------------+-----------------------+
|name|time         |H_evenement            |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+
|foo |1647932442000|2022-03-22 07:00:42.000|
|bar |1647932443000|2022-03-22 07:00:43.000|
|baz |1647932444000|2022-03-22 07:00:44.000|
+----+-------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Upvote too, if you like. :)